# How can I put my Java game in my Weebly Website?

Tags: java, web

I'm making a Java application (not applet), a game, which I want people to play through my weebly website because problems came for most of my friends PC's like the assets aren't appearing and the game is really slow.

**And what I want is to do is to put my Java game into my weebly website so my friends can play it without any problem.**

Should I make any changes to my program from Java application to an applet (please tell how because I don't know how), should I change Eclipse IDE which is the one I currently use to some other like NetBeans IDE? I'm not sure but I hope you all can help.

Comment: _"assets aren't are not appearing"_ You should make sure you package everything, and you make sure your paths are well defined. _"the game is really slow"_ If they use a laptop, your application is most likely not recognized as a 3d graphics app so it runs on the Intel chip instead of using the NVidia chip. They'd need to add your game to the list of apps run on the NVidia chip.

Comment: My rule of thumbs when I am looking related to Java, is typing "How to *Enter here*" in Google. For example "How to Applets" will give you all the informations you need to make your game an applet

Comment: i packaged everything and i said it doesn't work for most of my friends(that means it worked only for a few) and my problem isnt fixing the game fps or assets. I want to put my game in a weebly website(pls answer to the question ppl!!).

Comment: This feels like a [XY-question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Also running a game in a browser-applet isn't going fix the performance.

Comment: Pro tip: don't make applets. It's close to impossible to run them nowadays

Comment: im not trying to fix the performance, all i want is to put my game into a weebly website! pls just answer that or dont comment pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like we need to clarify a few things :

1. Changing your IDE is pretty unlikely to change anything to your problem. An IDE is just a tool to help you work, once you have your final application it does not matter which IDE you used.
2. Making your game an applet is also very unlikely to improve your performance problems as well as missing assets. Imho it will be even worse. You make an applet when you want to make it easier to the user to access the game as they do not need to download it, that's all. You should know that since 2013 and Oracle's change of policy concerning JWS and Applets, it has become a pain in the *** to deploy them.
3. If some of your friends do not see your assets, it is most likely due to something you did wrong. All you need to do is try to find what. Changing to Applets, or switching to javascript/C++/Python is not going to help.

Comment: For some of my friends, it WORKED FINE(with no issues), and for some it didnt,and all im asking is how can i put my game into a weebly website, PLS PPL just tell how to do that

Comment: If you really want to deploy your game as a Java Applet, I gave you the way to do that in comment : search "How to applets" in google, everything is explained